# Setting CheckListBox From MySQL Query

Tags: python, mysql, wxpython

My wxPython application has a has a window with a CheckListBox that displays all projects held in a MySQL database. For a selected employee the projects they are involved in should be ticked. I am trying to tick the boxes using:-

```
indices = [i for i in range(len(lst)) if lst[i][0] in prjs]
self.checkListBox1.SetChecked(indices)
```

where lst is a list of all the projects returned by cursor.fetchall() as shown below:-

lst is > ((3L, 'Blood pressure'), (1L, 'Cholesterol'), (2L, 'Diabetes'), (6L, 'Exercise'), (5L, 'Thyroid'), (4L, 'Weight/BMI')) <

and prjs the projects an employee in involved in:-

prjs are > ((2L,), (3L,), (6L,)) <

Setting the indices is failing because a tuple rather than a value is being returned. I could obviously 'mash' prjs to get it in the right format but is there a more elegant solution either in the MySQL return or in setting the indices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of hours I managed to get it sorted. My first attempt to convert prjs from  ((2L,), (3L,), (6L,)) to  (2L, 3L, 6L) failed as it ended up with as a string when I was trying to match on integers.

After delving some more on lists (Python lists and dictionaries are not my strong points) I came up with:-

```
prjs = [e for e, in row]
```

where e is the first element of the tuple and row is the result of:-

```
sql = "SELECT ProjectMembership.idProjectGroup FROM ProjectMembership \
    WHERE ProjectMembership.idPersonnel = " + str(PersonnelNo)
cursor.execute(sql)
row = cursor.fetchall()
```